# How to use random numbers properly in "Higher or Lower" game. I'm only a beginner

Tags: python, random, input, if-statement

Here's the code:

```
from random import *
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
r1 = choice (numbers)
r2 = choice (numbers)
print("H = HIGHER ,, L = LOWER ,, S = SAME")
print(r1)
a = input()
print(r2)
if r2 == r1 and a == 's':
     print("well done")
if r2 < r1 and a == 'l':
     print("well done")
if r2 > r1 and a == 'h':
     print("well done")
else:
     print("unlucky")
```

The problem is the very last part of the script. everything works perfectly except at the end of the script just after print(r2).... It all works but the answer keeps switching between "well done" and "unlucky". Sometimes it says both. Does anyone know what the problem is? My assumption that this was happening because of the simple reason it is random, and the first output (r1) changes as we move along the script. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no need to shout... that was quick @Junuxx!

Comment: I think you want If-Else conditions and one final Else (not three Ifs). The way it is now, one of the first two conditions could be met and you'll still get unlucky

Comment: I have tried that and many other different ways to do it. It still does not seem to work

Comment: As an aside, `from whatever import *` is not a good idea. Just import those functions (like `choice` here) that you'll actually need.

Comment: What is your expected output versus your observed output? If you've changed the `else`s to `elif`s you should not be getting multiple answers, and the random numbers will not change over the course of a single run of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fully functioning version of your program:

```
from random import choice

numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

r1 = choice(numbers)
r2 = choice(numbers)

print("h = HIGHER ,, l = LOWER ,, s = SAME")
print(r1)
a = raw_input()
print(r2)

if r2 == r1 and a == 's':
    print("well done")
elif r2 < r1 and a == 'l':
    print("well done")
elif r2 > r1 and a == 'h':
    print("well done")
else:
    print("unlucky")
```

I made it more [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) friendly.  Also, you should be displaying h, l and s... not H, L and S since your comparator against `a` uses lowercase.  Either that, or change the case of the input value.  Also, use `raw_input` instead of regular `input`.

As @Blorgbeard mentions, if you want the same random numbers chosen each time, then add this before you call `choice`

```
import random 
random.seed(1)
```

Comment: raw_input() did not work in python 3.2 but that doesn't matter because the script is now working. I think the problem was, as Abhranil Das also said, I had to type "from random import choice". Its working perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help everyone. I'm really delighted with this website it is a huge help :)

Comment: @DennisCallanan: Glad it is working for you.  I forgot to ask what version of Python you were using.  Since you are new to SO, I thought I would let you know that the proper action after you have solved your question is to mark an answer as `correct` by clicking the checkmark next to the left of the answer.  It appears that Blogbeard's answer is the one that should have actually corrected your problem (since the `from random import choice` would not make a difference as far as the way you were using it)

Answer (score 2):

Change your last two `if`s to `elif`s (elif means else-if):

```
if r2 == r1 and a == 's':
     print("well done")

elif r2 < r1 and a == 'l':
     print("well done")

elif r2 > r1 and a == 'h':
     print("well done")

else:
     print("unlucky")
```

Now "Unlucky" should only print if no other condition was met.

Comment: I have tried this. Made no difference whatsoever. Like I said, I don't know if this part is the problem. I could be using the random numbers the wrong way. I have a feeling the random numbers keep changing and this is why I get different answers

Comment: This will take care of the "sometimes it prints both" bit. The random numbers will keep changing every time you run the program, yes..

Comment: If you want to choose the same "random" numbers every time, you can call `random.seed(123)` (or whatever seed you want) at the start of your program